# How to delete user command message in discord.py?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have this code for the command. How to delete the user command message?

```py
@bot.command()
@commands.has_role("Referee")
async def game(ctx, winner, loser, score, MVP):
    teams = winner + " vs " + loser
    embed = discord.Embed(title = "Shell League Game | Season 1 ", color = 0xfca426)
    embed.add_field(name = "Teams", value = teams, inline = False)
    embed.add_field(name = "Score", value = score, inline = False)
    embed.add_field(name = "MVP", value = MVP, inline = False)
    await ctx.send(embed = embed)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to put `await ctx.message.delete()` at the beginning of your function definition. Here you go:

```py
@bot.command()
@commands.has_role("Referee")
async def game(ctx, winner, loser, score, MVP):
    await ctx.message.delete() # deletes author's command message
    # rest of your command's code
```

Comment: Still doesn't seem to work but thanks for trying

Comment: If it doesn't work, that means your bot doesn't have the `manage messages` permissions. I don't see any other reason as to why this wouldn't work.

Comment: I have given the bot full permissions, I think this is just one of those things that just don't work

Comment: @AdamHasan you can try this out too: `await ctx.channel.purge(limit=1)`